# LiPo Battery management circuits

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lipo

I am new to creating PCB designs for specific projects and I essentially need someone to help me verify if what I have done is correct. The power source is a USB-C connection supplying 5V to the entire board and the actual circuit is an ESP-12E I have already had the board built but I had issues with this specific part of the circuit where one of the traces was burning up when I flicked the switch (removed from diagram)

DataSheets I Used:

- [DW01A](https://hmsemi.com/downfile/DW01A.PDF)
- [TP4056](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf)

And this is a screenshot of the design I created using these datasheets.
[image: ![The design I created from the datasheets]

I also need some help with allowing it to charge while also cutting it off from the other components on the board. I have no clue where to place the switch on the diagram.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would have helped to know what the switch and the track that burned up was doing. As these schematics can't work, are these what you really use or something that does not match the actual design? See, the LEDs are upside down and battery has 100 ohms in series. You also do not show from where the 5V comes from, so it might be wrong too.

Comment: Updated the post with the entire diagram. This is a re-done diagram since the first design had 5V being shorted directly to GND, throught the switch. Which was a fuck up on my part. @Justme

Comment: Can you upload a better resolution picture?

Comment: What's the point of charging the battery, if the battery is not used?

Comment: @Justme Should I grab lines from the + and - terminals of the battery and tie them to the 5V and GND nets respectively?

Comment: @Nicroxio No, that would short the battery directly to the USB supply input, bypassing the charger and protection, and perhaps damaging the USB source and/or battery, and damaged batteries may burst up in flames or explode.

Comment: @Justme ok then, what do I do to use the battery instead of just having it charge? Diode? Idk I'm kinda just muddling my way though

Comment: @Nicroxio I don't know what you want the circuit to do, you never told that. You could start by telling what in the circuit should be powered by the battery, if you want something to be powered with the battery. You just said you need help verifying if something is correct, but it's impossible to verify if there is no knowledge what the circuit should do.

Comment: @Justme The board is an IMU based limb tracker for VR, its based on a design that was a series of seperated boards, I thought I'd give it a go to build it into a single board. Everything on the board needs to be either powered by usb when I am flashing the ESP/testing the output. and all other times powered by the battery.